# Tracking the usage of a Google Data Studio report

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio

I'm trying to track the usage of a Google Data Studio Report with Google Analytics. I tried to create a stream more than 24 hours ago but it still says **No Data received**. The stream "source" is a **Google Data Studio** report so I followed the advise of a blogger that seemed to help many other people but it doesn't work for me. I copied the Analytics tracking ID into the Google Data Studio report and I used https://datastudio.google.com as the stream URL in Google Analytics. Is this the right way of setting up the stream?

Also, do I need to wait for 24 hours every time after I tried to connect the stream before I know that it's working or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As such the domain does not matter, but setting it to datastudio.google.com won't hurt

And yes, max 24hr delay.

see https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7410792?hl=en for full instructions

Answer (score 0):

You can see the data studio usage information in real time if you connect your google analytics to bigquery, and then you might connect bigquery to datastudio.

In GA4, you need to go to Admin -> BigQuery Links and follow the steps to create the link. It is important to enable the daily and streaming options under the frequency section.

[image]

This connection will create a schema in the selected dataset with two tables: `events_` and `events_intraday_`. The `events_` table contains historical data and `events_intraday_` contains real time data. You might join them into a single table to obtain a real time and historical database all at once.

Finally, just import these tables into data studio, and appreciate your real time analytics of data studio usage.